# How to add pod dependency in kubernetes as like 'depends_on' in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

I need to start kubernetes pods in a sequence like pod2 should start only when pod1 is up and running.

we can do this in `docker-compose.yml` using `depends_on`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324677/wait-for-other-deployments-to-start-running-before-other-can-be-created/, see point 2) in original question.

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no built-in dependency management equivalent to `depends_on` available. In general, we assume loosely coupled services and as a good practice there should be no hard dependency in terms of start-up order, but retries and timeouts should be used. If you have to hardcode dependencies, you can use [init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). In your case, a init container in `pod2` could simply query if `pod1` (or better: the service in front of it) is ready in a while loop. The main container in `pod2` is guaranteed only to be launched if and when the init container exits successfully.

Comment: Why those two things should be mutually exclusive? Having retries doesn't mean there should be no dependencies. Having dependencies specified will likely speed-up start-up time of an app. I often see pods spinning in retries loop like mad until they finally make it in a correct order ... so not being able to specify dependencies easily is definitely not critical, but a nice to have feature.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a direct equivalent to dependency with Kubernetes primitives, as a workaround you can implement a readiness probe that will render pod2 unusable until it sees pod1 up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [`pod-dependency-init-container`](https://github.com/yogeshlonkar/pod-dependency-init-container) that I have build. This will check if any pod with given `labels` is running before starting your pod.